# CSS: How to add slanted edge to right of div with complete browser cross-compatability?

Tags: css

I'm looking to achieve a slanted edge on my div. The problem I'm coming across is the simple code I found to accomplish this is not cross-browser compatible. In fact, it only shows in Chrome.

Can anyone advise on how to do the following so it works in ALL browsers:

```
clip-path:polygon(0 0, 70% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
```

This effect would achieve:

[image: Desired slant]

Here's my entire CSS code:

```
.my-slanted-div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100px;
    padding:10px 10px;
    background-color:#eee;
    font-size:20px;
    clip-path:polygon(0 0, 70% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: maybe you can try placing a triangle on the right side

Comment: You can either use the border width trick, or use a background image gradient that is set at an angle.

Comment: @sniels you don't necessarily mean an image, right?

Comment: Generated content triangle using css

Comment: @Terry both sound like great options, but could you pose any examples?

Comment: @sniels if you feel like posing a working solution as an answer, feel free and I'll accept it!

Comment: You could always use an [SVG](http://caniuse.com/#search=SVG) instead of CSS to create your effect. You will have many more options for making it look pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick using borders.

```
<div id="container">
  <p id="text">Hello</p>
  <div id="slanted"></div>
</div>

#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background:url(http://placehold.it/200x200);
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

#slanted {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 75px solid #dedede;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #dedede;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcuzvyg6/2/)

Comment: This works great, though when you put text inside it's not positioned nicely. If you can fix that I think your method is better.

Comment: Wow, this is actually fantastic.

Comment: @sniels Yeah it's the one limitation of this approach, but if you know the size you can always just position it absolutely (or even move it relative to the parent). I've updated the example

Comment: this works for me, but a huge plus in the future is to have a solution (even this one) and be able to integrate a drop shadow to the `slanted` div

Answer (score 3):

You can also skew pseudo-element, like this:

```css
.my-slanted-div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:40px;
    left:0;
    width:80px;
    padding:10px 10px;
    background-color:red;
    font-size:20px;
   
  
   
}
.my-slanted-div:after {
  width:50px;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
 
  content:' ';
  right:-22px;
  top:0;
transform: skew(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="my-slanted-div">
TEXT
</div>
```

p.s. change angle, play with values...to get desired result...

Edit: Demo in context -> https://jsfiddle.net/Lbwj40mg/2/

Comment: That's a good solution. Though in some cases the text can get hidden by the skewed div.

Comment: @sniels, yes, but nothing which can't be fixed with proper z-index settings: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbwj40mg/1/ ;)

Comment: Thanks for a great solution!

Comment: @NoReceipt4Panda if one of these solutions solved your problem, you should consider accepting an answer

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely it is an SVG scaled to always fit its text which is simple and quick way of doing it; if you must use CSS then you could always:

- Set a gradient to the div from color to transparent so that it takes up most of the div and the transition of color is abrupt and not smooth like how a normal gradient looks.
- create another div and using borders create a triangle to touch the other main rectangular div such as doing:

  `.triangle { 
     width: 0;
     height: 0; 
     border-style: solid; 
     border-width: 200px 200px 0 0; 
     border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent; 
  }`

Comment: awesome solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've made it work one way with :before and :after pseudos, you simply need to update the widths, heights and line-height to suit the size of tab you want; the rectangle must be the same height as the :before and :after bits for a clean look.

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
.box:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}
.box:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Text in the box
</div>
```

Comment: btw clip-path has never worked in IE and they aren't supporting it in Edge either, unfortunately: http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: That's a shame, would have been a simple way to go about this. (just one line). Oh well, what can you do. Great insight Nathaniel!

Comment: Yes, inconsistencies between browsers is a challenge we wrestle with every day, aye. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with transform: rotate just to add to the list. Quite annoying as you will have to play with pixels for alignment and make some entries into @media rules for different screen sizes. But it should be fairly cross browser friendly (but maybe not  opera mini)

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}
.container {
  position: absolute; /* needs a position, relative is fine. abolsute just for this example */
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden; /* required */
}

.salutations {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 15px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px; /* match height to vertically center text */
  font-size: 30px;

}
.salutations::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px; /* play with this for alignment */
  right: -36px; /* play with this for alignment */
  height: 40px; width: 70px; /* may need to adjust these depending on container size */
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  transform: rotate(60deg); /* to adjust angle */
  z-index: -1; /* puts the pseudo element ::before below .salutations */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="salutations">Hello</div>
</div>
```

P.S. May have to adjust a pixel or two, my eyes suck.

**Browser Compatability**

[transform: rotate](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

[pseudo elements (::before)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent)

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/wy5bjxg3/

Answer (score 0):

Using css you can generate an element that takes the shape of a triangle.
Css tricks has a [post](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) on that.

By making the `.slanted` class position itself relative, we can position the generated content on the right side of the slanted div using absolute positioning.
It'll take some fiddling to get the perfect result you want, but here's an example.

```css
.slanted{
  background: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
 }
.slanted::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 29px 0 0 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slanted">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Here's a [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) to generated content using `::after` to generate the triangle.